# Conversion of JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, postman

In postman Im passing a raw data, so that the json in the `body` is added to the backend service.

```
 {
  "emails": ["dfakeId@gmail.com"],
  "subject": "Test",
  "body": "{\n   \"sendname\": \"kil\",\n   \"sendDD\": \"US\",\n   \"sendcontact\": \"797979\",\n   \"sendemail\": \"kil@mail.com\",\n   \"sendtime\": \"21:08\"\n   }"
}
```

If you notice the json in the body it is represented differently, `"body": "{\n   \"sendname\": \"kil\",\n   \"sendDD\": \"US\",\n   \"sendcontact\": \"797979\",\n   \"sendemail\": \"kil@mail.com\",\n   \"sendtime\": \"21:08\"\n   }"`,

But Im able to get only the normal json `"body": {"sendname": "ok","sendDD": "US","sendcontact": "900","sendemail": "ok@mail.oc","sendtime": "21:00","sendData": "300"}` in my code, so whenever data is passed to back-end Im getting error:403(forbidden error). So how to convert or render the json like the above, so that the data can be saved in the back-end successfully. Looking for help thankyou.

Comment: are you sending the headers, content-type application/json?

Comment: Im not sending the header but passing the content-type application/json

Comment: i mean, in postman. You select raw. To the right there's the option to select the content type.

Comment: In your backend code, you should be able to use `JSON.stringify(req.body.body)`. I think it just automatically parses json objects. Are you using express by any chance?

Comment: ok, Im sorry, Im setting both the header and content-type to application/json

Comment: @Brian Im not using express. HTML ,jquery

Comment: @sree Ah, I misread. You should be able to do that on the frontend as well. If you use `JSON.stringify(obj)`, it gets transformed into a string like in your body field. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Brian, I tried using `JSON.stringify(obj)` but this how it looks `{



"sendname": "pop",



"sendDD": "US",



"sendcontact": "90080",



"sendemail": "pop@mail.com",



"sendtime": "09:00"
}`

Comment: @Brian, but I want something like `"body": "{\n   \"sendname\": \"kil\",\n   \"sendDD\": \"US\",\n   \"sendcontact\": \"797979\",\n   \"sendemail\": \"kil@mail.com\",\n   \"sendtime\": \"21:08\"\n   }"`, so this make storing the data easy.

Comment: This that you want is a string.  When you should be wanting an object. An object is what you will be able to save. What's the output of console.log(typeof [yourReceivedData])

Comment: try using `JSON.stringfy(JSON.stringfy(dataToBePassed))`